# While installing ftp vsftpd, tomcat7 error is coming

Tags: 12.04, vsftpd, tomcat7

```
root@Nanobi-05-PC:/home/dev# sudo apt-get install -f vsftpd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vsftpd is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 56 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up tomcat7 (7.0.52-1ubuntu0.3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/tomcat7.config: 11: /etc/default/tomcat7: is: not found
dpkg: error processing package tomcat7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tomcat7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

how to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your tomcat7 installation is broken. Try to uninstall tomcat:

```
    sudo apt-get purge tomcat7
```

and then install tomcat7 again (if needed)

```
    sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

If everything is ok, then you probably will be able to install vsftpd.

UPDATE:
Other suggestions:

1. Tomcat7 deb package is broken. Try to find and delete a tomcat7 deb package file from apt-get cache. It is located in /var/cache/apt/archives. Then run "purge" and "install" commands as i described before. On "sudo apt-get install tomcat7" - apt must download a new one.
2. Tomcat7 installation is broken. If apt-get totally refuse to work, you may force reinstall tomcat7 manually. Try this (but you must specify correct package name from your apt cache):

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/tomcat7_7.0.52-1ubuntu0.3_all.deb
   ```

if there is no tomcat7 package in /var/cache/apt/archives - then you should  run this:

```
    sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

and then try to reinstall again.

Comment: i tried this still it's not working

Comment: Give an output, please.